# How do I know if raw sockets are enabled in Windows 7?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I'm currently working on an app in C++ as for studying tcp/ip raw sockets on a Win7 box.

I want to know if my OS has raw sockets enabled, and if not, is there 
any way to enable them?

I can see from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#limitations_on_raw_sockets) that Winsock has limitations in Win7 (again: is it possible to unlock it since its my box, I have admin privileges).
Moreover, despite of those referenced limitations, is it possible at least, for me to complete the TCP 3-way presentation?

Maybe my last option would be using Winpcap library.

Answer (score 1):

Windows supports raw sockets [natively](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740548%28VS.85%29.aspx).

> The Microsoft implementation of TCP/IP
>   on Windows is capable of opening a raw
>   UDP or TCP socket based on the above
>   restrictions. Other Winsock providers
>   may not support the use of raw
>   sockets.

Comment: Ok, clarifying myself better, what i mean is if i can unlock Microsoft tcp/ip implementation in order to fully use raw sockets without this limitations. My goal is to play around with tcp protocol.

Comment: @EJP Take a look at the following link, on the section entitled "Limitations on Raw Sockets": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please read this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740548(v=vs.85).aspx

And by the way I am also searching on how to lift those limitations.